# Angular2 - Change Component value in another component

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my main component

```
export class MonitorCreateComponent {
name: string;
availableTypes = ["Flow","Server","Process","Website"]; 
selectedType = "Flow";
 }
```

availableTypes are for dropdown and the selecteType is first one. I am showing those in one of the views and working fine. Now, I am accessing this component in another component. I want to remove/hide the Flow and want to change the selectedType to server. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can create a service and make MonitoreCreateComponent subscribed to it. Then you can set value in your another component and retrieve them. Here is how : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selectedType to be transfered to the server the right way to do it is to create a Service that handles communication with the server. Access it via dependency injection.

This service can be injected into both components and the communication can go through the service. That way you can communicate without sending it to the server.

If you want to send it to server you can send it in one service and get it from another service.

Access between components there is an exellent blogpost about this:
http://mean.expert/2016/05/21/angular-2-component-communication/